# VBA loop: How to get Ticker symbols into Ticker column?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

How do I populate the Ticker column from each sheet for example from pic1 to pic2 using VBA?, attached is the code I am using but it creates the headers fine on each sheet but not able to populate the Ticker column. I would like to populate the ticker column and later on the yearly change, percent change columns and so on.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Stock_market()

'Declare and set worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet

'Loop through all stocks for one year
For Each ws In Worksheets


'Create the column headings
ws.Range("I1").Value = "Ticker"
ws.Range("J1").Value = "Yearly Change"
ws.Range("K1").Value = "Percent Change"
ws.Range("L1").Value = "Total Stock Volume"

ws.Range("P1").Value = "Ticker"
ws.Range("Q1").Value = "Value"
ws.Range("O2").Value = "Greatest % Increase"
ws.Range("O3").Value = "Greatest % Decrease"
ws.Range("O4").Value = "Greatest Total Volume"

'Define Ticker variable
Dim Ticker As String
Ticker = " "
Dim Ticker_volume As Double
Ticker_volume = 0

'Create variable to hold stock volume
'Dim stock_volume As Double
'stock_volume = 0

'Set initial and last row for worksheet
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Integer

'Define Lastrow of worksheet
Lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Set new variables for prices and percent changes
Dim open_price As Double
open_price = 0
Dim close_price As Double
close_price = 0
Dim price_change As Double
price_change = 0
Dim price_change_percent As Double
price_change_percent = 0



'Do loop of current worksheet to Lastrow
For i = 2 To Lastrow

'Ticker symbol output
If ws.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> ws.Cells(i, 1).Value Then
Ticker = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value

'Calculate change in Price
close_price = ws.Cells(i, 6).Value
price_change_percent = close_price - open_price

'Fixing the open price equal zero problem
ElseIf open_price <> 0 Then
price_change_percent = (price_change_percent / open_price) * 100

End If

Next i

Next ws

End Sub
```

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

Comment: After this line `Ticker = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value` try this `ws.Cells(i, "I").Value2 = Ticker`

Comment: After adding that new line, what i get is single A in row 263 in  the Ticker columns, AA in row 525 and so on. so its not listing it as A then AA in the next row

Comment: Oh so you need another variable to keep the ticker row in. I've put an answer below, please check out the `Dim` of a new `TickerRow` variable before the `i` loop and the addition to itself if the ticker changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim TickerRow As Long: TickerRow = 1

'Do loop of current worksheet to Lastrow
For i = 2 To Lastrow

'Ticker symbol output
If ws.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> ws.Cells(i, 1).Value Then
TickerRow = TickerRow + 1
Ticker = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
ws.Cells(TickerRow, "I").Value = Ticker

'Calculate change in Price
close_price = ws.Cells(i, 6).Value
price_change_percent = close_price - open_price

'Fixing the open price equal zero problem
ElseIf open_price <> 0 Then
price_change_percent = (price_change_percent / open_price) * 100

End If

Next i
```